# 500 View not found [name, type, prefix]

Tags: php, joomla

I don't know where this bug is. I tried making several changes in my view but still error remains.

**Here is my view/tmpl/view.html.php**

```
jimport('joomla.application.component.view');

class CommentViewComment extends JViewLegacy{

    function display($com = null)
    {
        // Assign data to the view
        $this-> msg = 'Comment';

        // Display the view
        parent::display($com);
    }
```

Please help to remove this error

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to place your file in **views/Comment/view.html.php** and **views/Comment/tmpl/default.php**

Comment: Yes, you are right. my view.html.php file is in View/comment and default file is in tmpl folder under View/comment. I also tried changing class name into commentViewcomment